# HitTest the ball (object) gets hit before it hits the board

Tags: javascript

I have created one function which counts the hit of the ball to the board. The hit function works but it count the hit before the ball hits the board
Am i doing anything wrong? 
    // hitTest

```
function hitTest(rect1, rect2) {
    if (rect1.x >= rect2.x + rect2.width || rect1.x + rect1.width <= rect2.x 
|| 
rect1.y >= rect2.y + rect2.height || rect1.y + rect1.height <= rect2.y) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function doHitTest() {
    "use strict";
//board vs ball
    for (var i = balls.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (hitTest(bounceBoard, balls[i])) {
            console.log("HIT");
            stage.removeChild(balls[i]);
            balls.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: if `x` and `y` are respectively leftmost and topmost coordinates, it's not clear why do you need to add width and height to them. Shouldn't it be like  `if (a.x <= b.x || a.x + a.width >= b.x + b.width)`?

Comment: As a sidenote, are your balls rectangular? That sounds really weird. ) Using `ballBoundingRects` or something (that means the squares around the balls) sounds a bit better.

Comment: A Note: I would suggest you to properly parenthesise your conditionals which will save you from operator precedence related issues plus it'll increase readability of your code.